# whats wrong in this program?

Tags: c

Am unable to run this code...

```
#include<cstdio>
int main()
{
struct a{
    int b;
    struct a *next;
};

    typedef struct a no;

    no *n;

    n->b = 12;
    n->next = NULL;

    n->next->b = 12;
    n->next->next = NULL;

    printf("%d %d", n->b, n->next->b);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what message comes up(i'm feeling lazy)

Comment: Does it compile?  If not, what are the error messages?  What happens when you try to run it?  What outcome did you expect to happen?  What do you want us to do about it?

Comment: Do not use use HTML tags to format your code. Select the code in the editor and hit the `{}` button. And make your mind up if you are using C or C++.

Answer (score 6):

When you say:

```
no *n;
```

you get an uninitialised pointer. When you use that pointer, you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: And then there's still the `n->next = NULL; n->next->b = 12;` issue after that.

Comment: @sakthi Reading a book on C or C++ would be  a good start, as would initialising the pointer. Your code has lots else wrong with it, however.

Comment: I did the malloc thing .. clear this  n->next = NULL; n->next->b = 12;n->next = NULL; n->next->b = 12; issue pls

Answer (score 0):

You allocated space for a pointer to a structure, but you didn't allocate space for the actual structure.  This means that you don't have a memory address for the structure you are using.

In addition, the pointer points to some random memory address because you didn't initialize it.  As a result, you could be trying to read and write to memory that doesn't belong to you, which can cause your program or even your system to crash because of the undefined behavior that results.

Answer (score 0):

As @Neil Butterworth said, you get an uninitialised pointer. This mean that this pointer could point to anywhere, thus giving an access violation error. The way to fix this is simple, just call malloc() before using that pointer. malloc() gives that pointer a valid and usable address, so no one will complain about that.

Comment: Hmmm ... you need to check the return value of `malloc` before using it.

Comment: @pmg: I took it for granted :P

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a `struct` **INSIDE** a function.

Declare the `struct` **OUTSIDE** of the function.

The `typedef` should be declared outside the function too.

```
#include<cstdio>

struct a{
    int b;
    struct a *next;
};

    typedef struct a no;

int main()
{

 ///... your code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

`no *n = (no*)malloc(sizeof(no));`

Comment: In C the cast is redundant and may hide an error. Don't cast the return value of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdio>

/* declaring the struct in the function definition may be possible (I'm not sure,
   actually, haha).  Unless you have a GOOD reason, it's good practice to declare
   structs, globals, typedefs, etc... outside the function */

typedef struct a{
    int b;
    struct a *next;
} no;

int main()
{
    no *n;

    /* Here, you have a pointer.  Remember these are simply (generally) 32-bit values
       defined in your stack space used to store a memory location which points to your
       ACTUAL struct a!  Depending on what USED to be in the stack space, this could
       point ANYWHERE in memory, but usually you will find that it points to the NULL
       memory location, which is just address "0".  To get this to point to something,
       you have to allocate empty space on your heap to store your struct... */

    n = malloc(sizeof(no));

    /* Now your pointer n points to an allocated 'struct a', and you can use it like
       normal */

    n->b = 12;
    n->next = NULL;

    /* You just set n->next, which is another 'no' pointer, to NULL.  This means that
       n->next points nowhere.  So, just like above you have to malloc another instance
       of the struct! */

    n->next = malloc(sizeof(no));

    /* NOW you can use n->next with no ill effects! */

    n->next->b = 12;
    n->next->next = NULL;

    printf("%d %d", n->b, n->next->b);
    getchar();

    /* After you're done with your structs, you want to free them using the POINTERS
       that reference them */

    free(n->next);
    free(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `n->next = malloc(sizeof(no));`?

Comment: -1: if `malloc` behaves the same in C++ as it does in C, you absolutely need to check the return value before using it.

Comment: @Jan Yes, you're right, sorry about the typo.  I didn't try and compile/run this, I just typed it out quickly.

Comment: @pmg While you're 'absolutely' correct, you SHOULD always check the return value of a malloc in any final code, I was trying to be more explicit of what needs to happen without adding too much, which obfuscates the answer.  After all, the original question pointed to the fact that @sakthi did not understand the difference between declaring a datatype and declaring a pointer to a datatype.  I was just trying to make it clear in the original context of the code unlike the rest of these answers.  (That's how things are made most clear to me... Maybe I'm alone there?)

Comment: @Lncn: exactly because the OP seems a beginner, I think answers should be more complete and leave nothing implicit (adding the NULL check doesn't obfuscate). This level of helpfulness reminds me of someone learning to drive without ever learning about fuel: everything works (gear shift, braking, turning, ...) until fuel runs out :)

Comment: @pmg I do have to disagree with that. You can't possibly try and explain the intricacies of every function right off the bat to a programmer who is still grasping the pointer concept.  I will agree, though, that verifying the return value of malloc is not NULL before using it is pretty elementary and maybe I should have pointed that out, but that wasn't the point of my answer.  I assume he isn't running this on some embedded processor with limited RAM... I guarantee this malloc will succeed ~100% of the time he runs this on his computer, so it wasn't worth explicitly checking in the answer.

Comment: @pmg I don't mean to sound like my panties are in a wad, I just don't think my answer deserved to be voted down because of that... I'm alright about it now, though. Haha :)  (I'm new to this whole stackoverflow thing, if you couldn't tell)

Comment: I revoked the -1 (after my unrelated edit), even though I think my point is valid: if you're supplying a program as an answer, do make it complete.

Comment: @pmg You didn't have to do that. You live and learn. Thanks though... for what it's worth